# Query for fetching records from SQLite database on Blackberry

Tags: sqlite, java

I want to fetch data from SQLite database for Blackberry.

There is one table with four columns: `ID, FROM, TO, TIME`

I want to fetch record on the basis of `FROM`, and `TO` values.

Where condition 1:

```
FROM = [from value] AND TO = [to value]
```

2nd condition is:

```
FROM = TO AND TO = FROM
```

It should return the last 20 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are after. So, this guess may be wrong:

```
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE ( fromUserID = @From AND toUserID = @To )
   OR ( fromUserID = @To AND toUserID = @From )
ORDER BY TimeSent DESC
  LIMIT 20 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Messages
(
    MessageID INT
    , fromUserID INT
    , toUserID INT
    , TimeSent DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (1, 10, 11, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (2, 11, 10, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (3, 11, 12, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (4, 11, 10, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (5, 11, 12, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (6, 11, 10, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (7, 11, 12, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (8, 11, 12, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (9, 11, 10, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (10, 11, 12, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (11, 11, 10, GetDate());
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (12, 11, 12, GetDate());

DECLARE @t TABLE (MessageID INT);
DECLARE @From INT;
DECLARE @To INT;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT fromUserID, toUserID
FROM Messages
GROUP BY fromUserID, toUserID;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @From, @To;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t
    SELECT TOP(2) MessageID
    FROM Messages
    WHERE fromUserID = @From AND toUserID = @To
    ORDER BY TimeSent DESC;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @From, @To;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
SELECT * 
FROM Messages 
    INNER JOIN @t tt ON Messages.MessageID = tt.MessageID
```

This returns the 2 most recent messages for each conversation between fromUserID and toUserID.  Change the `TOP(2)` to `TOP(20)` to get the 20 most recent conversations.

I'm sure this is not the most optimal way to do this; I believe it can be done in a set-based manner as opposed to the cursor-based, procedural manner shown here.